# FreeBSD bridge ARP replies not forwarded

Tags: freebsd, bridge, arp

I have a bridge between two networks using the same address space, and have very strange issues with ARP packets.

Interface bridge0 has no IP address assigned, and has two members : em1 and em2.

A virtual machine on em2 interface side is sending ARP requests, asking for physical address of gateway that is on em1 interface side but the replies are only to be seen on em1, not getting forwarded to the machine.

```
em1
11:20:59.121901 00:50:56:b8:13:53 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.22.254 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) tell 192.168.22.204, length 46
11:20:59.122067 00:50:56:b8:13:53 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.22.254 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) tell 192.168.22.204, length 46
11:20:59.122780 00:00:0c:9f:f1:e2 > 00:50:56:b8:13:53, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Reply 192.168.22.254 is-at 00:00:0c:9f:f1:e2, length 46

em2
11:20:59.121884 00:50:56:b8:13:53 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.22.254 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) tell 192.168.22.204, length 46
11:20:59.122079 00:50:56:b8:13:53 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.22.254 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) tell 192.168.22.204, length 46
```

Both pf and IPFW firewalls are disabled, I'm using 10.3-RELEASE

Answer (score 1):

00:50:56 is a VMware MAC address. If ESX and this FreeBSD system is a VM, you must enable promiscuous mode on the port group that VM is connected to on both its ports. Though tcpdump on the VM should still show it in that case, it'd just be dropped at the ESX level.

Post the output of 'ifconfig bridge0' and 'ifconfig bridge0 addr'.